# Can't install vulkan with mesa driver on amd gpu

Tags: amd-graphics, mesa, vulkan

I have an amd radeon r9 390 gpu.
Using Ubuntu 16.04 - kernel: 4.14.6-041406-generic

I am using oibaf's ppa https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers

> glxinfo | grep OpenGL

Gives the following output:

```
OpenGL vendor string: X.Org
OpenGL renderer string: AMD HAWAII (DRM 2.50.0 / 4.14.6-041406-generic, LLVM 5.0.1)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 17.4.0-devel
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 17.4.0-devel
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.1 Mesa 17.4.0-devel
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.10
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

X server version: X.Org X Server 1.18.4

I followed the installation guide at 
https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/sdk/1.0.65.0/linux/getting_started.html

When I run type "vulkaninfo" I get the following output:

```
    Vulkan API Version: 1.0.65


Instance Extensions:
====================
Instance Extensions count = 10
    VK_KHR_external_fence_capabilities  : extension revision  1
    VK_KHR_external_memory_capabilities : extension revision  1
    VK_KHR_external_semaphore_capabilities: extension revision  1
    VK_KHR_get_physical_device_properties2: extension revision  1
    VK_KHR_get_surface_capabilities2    : extension revision  1
    VK_KHR_surface                      : extension revision 25
    VK_KHR_wayland_surface              : extension revision  6
    VK_KHR_xcb_surface                  : extension revision  6
    VK_KHR_xlib_surface                 : extension revision  6
    VK_EXT_debug_report                 : extension revision  8
/tmp/SDK-DEV/Build/Vulkan-LoaderAndValidationLayers/demos/vulkaninfo.c:1670: failed with VK_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED
```

I previously had vulkan working with amd-gpu-pro driver. But I decided to try this oibaf's ppa for playing World of Warcraft with better performance. Any suggestions to what my problem is, or to further troubleshooting the problem?

Comment: Can anyone help me on this? bump..